# HP Laserjet 2600n on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-printer

I'm in the process of migrating printers to a new Print Server, running Microsoft Server 2008 R2, for the most part it's been going fine. But we have a problem with a HP LaserJet 2600n. This printer is not supported by HP Universal Printer drivers, nor has its drivers been updated passed Server 2003. I've tried all the drivers that HP offer on there site for the 2600n, but none seems to work.

So I ask here if anyone has successfully managed to get this printer working on Windows server 2008 and how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
In the end we replaced the printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the printer, as it is not supported and does not work on Windows 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

I have had huge problems installing HP printers on server 2003 & 2008 
not on a dedicated print server but on a general use terminal server.

my workaround was to map the HP Laserjet 4 drivers to the printer and then trick windows into thinking it is the correct driver by editing the WTSUPRN.inf file

more info on the full process here:
 http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/terminal-services/tshp.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use the Windows 7 x64 printer driver, available @ http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=446154&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=446153&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=4063

Comment: Tried them. They want the printer connected via USB, not networked. I managed to get round that, but once installed they cause explorer to crash when you open print properties.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the Windows 7 64 bit driver package.
Begin the install and it will stall at "Connect via USB"... AFTER it pre-loads the drivers.
Cancel the loader.
Go to Add Printer and add a local printer.
When you get to the drivers, the 2600n will be listed in the HP drivers available.